# can't update list adapter in list view while posting in onPostExecute adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, reload

Basically i have been try to do the damn this for over 40 hours - read all threads about it and still no result!!! So I can't update list adapter in list view while posting in onPostExecute  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ProgressDialog dialog;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            Table.this);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Загружаю. Подождите..."); 

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> loadingTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {                                     
              dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {                 

  ........ adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Table.this,         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,CreateStringArray
   .getString(myData, null, null, null, null));

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();      
         Table.this.
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    };          
    loadingTask.execute();  



    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
```

So it shows me the spinner and successfully load and deletes it. After a while of debugging i noticed that it successfully changes data in the adapter. Still it dent display it. Am working with listvew

Comment: you forget to set `adapter` to your `ListView`

Comment: no i didn't look after super.oncreate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By instantiating a new Adapter in `doInBackGround` you lose the reference to the adapter you set doing `setListAdapter(adapter);` Therefore, the adapter you notify in OnPostExecute is not the one in your ListView.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why it's not the same witch i put before on create. And i did set the adapter after super.oncreate   Sorry for being ask inet was down(  Is there a method to switch to new adapter without loosing reference?

Comment: You could call setListAdapter again.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  
          //    ((BaseAdapter) Table.this.getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
             setListAdapter(adapter);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

Comment: thnx everything worked just deleted this adapter in the header and initialized in doinbackground than transfer to post execute